# export-csv failing where out-file succeeds?

Tags: powershell

I do not understand why I am getting no data on a csv from

```
$users=gc C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\OCH\old_users.txt
foreach ($user in $users)
{
get-aduser -identity $user -pr * | Select-Object name, samaccountname, telephonenumber |export-csv C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\1.csv -notype
}
```

When I ruin the below, with out-file -append, it does have data

```
$users=gc C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\OCH\old_users.txt
foreach ($user in $users)
{
get-aduser -identity $user -pr * | Select-Object name, samaccountname, telephonenumber |out-file -append C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\1.txt 
}
```

Comment: For starters In the `export-csv` example you are not `-append`ing. Don't use `-Properties *` when you only need the `telephonenumber`.  `-Properties telephonenumber`. You could be writing bad data that is overwriting good results.

Comment: I just ran the following with the same results...this is a weird one, there are alot of errors in the data because the account cannot be found, but there are a few valid accounts in the data, and those show up with out-file, but not export-csv                                                                                    $users=gc C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\OCH\old_users.txt
foreach ($user in $users)
{
get-aduser -identity $user -pr telephonenumber |export-csv -append C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\1.csv -NoTypeInformation 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `-Append` in your `export-csv` example. I would guess that you are overwriting it with bad data (That being said I would have expected one result in your output file). Consider the following example instead which streamlines the entire process and works with the pipeline so that `-Append` is not needed.

```
Get-Content "C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\OCH\old_users.txt" | ForEach-Object{ 
    get-aduser -identity $_ -Properties telephonenumber | Select-Object name, samaccountname, telephonenumber
} | Export-Csv C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I also wonder if you are suppressing errors? Check the results of `$ErrorActionPreference` which typically is Continue

`Get-Aduser` returns no object if no matching user is found. I think your are expecting blank output for those when there is none. You need to have some error detection in your logic to account for those. Not the only way but we get the user into the variable `$result`. If data exists pass it along the pipe. If not we create an empty entry to be moved along as well.

```
Get-Content "C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\OCH\old_users.txt" | ForEach-Object{ 
    $result = get-aduser -identity $_ -Properties telephonenumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    If($result){
        $result | Select-Object name, samaccountname, telephonenumber
    } Else {
        New-Object -TypeName Psobject -Property @{
            Name = $_
            samaccountname = ""
            telephonenumber = ""
        }
    }

} | Export-Csv C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I just ran the following with the same results...this is a weird one, there are alot of errors in the data because the account cannot be found, but there are a few valid accounts in the data, and those show up with out-file, but not export-csv $users=gc C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\OCH\old_users.txt foreach ($user in $users) { get-aduser -identity $user -pr telephonenumber |export-csv -append C:\0NIX\03SCRIPTS\TMP\1.csv -NoTypeInformation }

Comment: I just ran your linked script as is and it also returned no data.  I am wondering if export-csv is having  a hard time because 90% of the accounts in the users txt file are deleted.

Comment: And yes $erroractionpreference is set to "continue"

Comment: @200mg If the users are erroring out then there is not object to send to Export-CSV. You need to have some error detection in there for that. See my update

Comment: "@Matt" Not all users are erroring out....when I run the exact same command, but pipe the data to "out-file -append", there is data, but when I pipe it to export-csv, there is no data.  Both commands are referencing the same .txt file for the user list.

Comment: @200mg First. Run my updated code and let me know if its working for you. Second `Export-CSV` works with objects.. and `Out-File` will take anything as long as it can be made into a string. That is an important difference. If you reduce your sample to a list of known existing users you should have output. Its the non results that are causing an issue here.

Comment: OK, I'll check it out, thanks for your help, yeah, i was kind of figuring that the csv thing was due to the amount of errors, i tested my original script on a known enabled list of users and it worked fine.